# Using rel canonical on Blogger to point to an external blog

Tags: html, blogger, canonical-link

I am trying to set up canonical link items on each of my blog posts on Blogger so that I can make sure that Google knows that the preferred version is on my own external site.

How do I add this element in the Theme HTML so it does this automatically for each post?  Assuming that the titles and the slugs are going to be identical on Blogger and the external site.

I know this will make it so the Blogger page is the canonical:

```
<link expr:href='data:blog.canonicalUrl' rel='canonical'/>
```

But I want it so that the external page is the canonical.  Is there something I can do like this?:

```
<link expr:href='https://www.myexternalsite.com/blog/ + some automated slug' rel='canonical'/>
```